# LXR setup, all done, but the page said "Unrecoverable error, No known root for source-tree lxr", why?

Tags: web-services, cross-compiling, symbols, lxr

I install LXR in my PC to build reference of Linux source code, I follow the step of LXR manual, every thing is done, but when I open my website, the page said "Unrecoverable error, No known root for source-tree lxr", could anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recently encountered the same problem after
having to reinstall everything on my server

for me, the problem was 
misspelled 'host_names' parameter in lxr.conf file

the apache server wasn't able to the config through the name given in the URL

maybe you should check if the path leading up to your lxr.conf file is readable by user 
'www-data'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had solve the problem, as you say.